# Should I use ng-app directive in every page for a non single page application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, model-view-controller

I am developing a web application for a game using MVC but the views are different (there is a CreateGameView.html, a GameView.html ...) meaning there is not a shared navigation bar. I am using AngularJS.

When clicking some buttons in a page some Controller perform some action and then another View (html page) is loaded.

The question is should I use the ng-app directive in each html page using a Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use one `ng-app` directive. Instead use ngroute to control your view. There is a short tutorial on w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

Below is the gist of it.

index.html

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

<!-- if you wanted a common navbar -->
<navbar></navbar>

<div ng-view></div>

</body>
```

starScreenView.html

```
<p><a href="/createGame">New Game</a></p>
<p><a href="/loadGame">Load Game</a></p>
```

createGameView.html

```
<p>This will be the create game view</p>
<p><a href="/">Main Menu</a></p>
<p><a href="/loadGame">Load Game</a></p>
```

gameView.html

```
<p>This will be the game view</p>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "startScreenView.html",
        controller: "startScreenCtrl"
    })
    .when("/createGame", {
        templateUrl : "createGameView.html",
        controller: "createGameCtrl"
    })
    .when("/loadGame", {
        templateUrl : "gameView.html",
        controller: "gameViewCtrl"
    })
});
```

What is happening is the `ng-view` is being replaced with the templateUrl html page, and this block has the controller wrapped around it.

For each routing end point you can have a page, controller, pass parameters around, etc. Just search google for ngroute examples.

Comment: But the new html page is loaded in the div with ng-view directive right? I dont want the links for the New Game and Load Game to be present in the new page loaded.

Comment: Yes, those links would actually be in the startScreenView.html

Comment: Yes, but I dont want those links to be in the createGameView.html or gameView.html.

Comment: @MABC I broke up the html to hopefully make it more clear. Check out the edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you must have separate HTML pages and you plan to use Angular on all of those pages then you need an `ng-app` on all those pages.

Otherwise use the router or craft your own way of swapping page content. If you page is simple enough you may not need the extra size of the router.